# Dynamically generate new class objects from different classes

Tags: c++, object, reflection, polymorphism, metaprogramming

I'm currently writing a simulator for a card game. I'm trying to code a move generator. I have got a base class "Card" from which I'm deriving every card (around 150 different ones). They are pretty specific so I can't implement them within a single class (and I don't want to use any scripting language).

What I need (want) to do:
Code 150 classes derived from "Card". Now I need to generate new objects during runtime and push them into my board.

For example:

```
std::vector<Card*> board;
board.push_back(new Card132());
```

So how would I be able to do this - cause I need to decide **during runtime** which object (from which class) I need to generate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the basis for choosing between `Card132` and `CardNNN`?

Comment: The design has an odour about it, but you can always just use an array of factory functions.

Comment: First of all consider storing [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) in your vector.

Comment: **150** representations of a card is _ridiculous_ and dare I say unnecessary!!!! Learn inheritance, composition, etc. etc. and don't be all hackish with you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a factory pattern.

An object of each class is statically instantiated and registers itself in a map with a name. All classes derive from the same base.

When you want to construct an object of a specific type, pass it's name to the factory, lookup the type, generate a new one and return it via a base pointer object.

Adding new card is then a matter of coding a new class and having it register its name with the factory.

Answer (score 0):

The code ust be able to decide himself which card to generate.

```
if (want to generate card 1)
{
    board.push_back(new Card1());
}
else if (want to generate card 2)
{
    board.push_back(new Card2());
}
else if ...
```